# Multiple class methods adding to string

Tags: php

I have a string of data that will be written to a file as a log of events, so I need this string available from the time the page begins to load to the time it is completed loading, at which time the contents of the string are written to the log file.

I am able to add to this string across some classes, but not others so it has me confused. When it doesn't work I get an 'allowed memory size of ... exhausted' error.

FILE: index.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/'.$class.'.class.php')) {

        include dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/'.$class.'.class.php';

    }

});

$App = new Core();

$App->Visitor->getIP(); // This will exhaust memory...why?
$App->Settings->hello(); // Works
$App->writeLog('in my index file...'); // Works

$App->viewLog();
```

FILE: /classes/Core.class.php

```
class Core {

    public static $logContent;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->initialize();

    }

    private function initialize() {
        self::$logContent = 'Lets start...';
        $this->Visitor = new Visitor($this);
        $this->Settings = new Settings($this);
        $this->Cache = new Cache($this);    
    }

    public function writeLog($action) {
      self::$logContent .= $action;
    }

    public function viewLog() {
      echo self::$logContent;
    }

}
```

FILE: /classes/Visitor.class.php

```
class Visitor {

    private $App;

    public function __construct($App) {

        $this->App = $App;

    }

    public function getIP() {

        $this->App->writeLog('getting ip...'); // Exhausts memory

        if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

            return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

        } else {    

            return false;   
        }

    }

}
```

FILE: /classes/Settings.class.php

```
class Settings {

    private $App;

    public function __construct($App) {

        $this->App = $App;

    }


    public function hello() {
        $this->App->writeLog('getting ip...');
        return 'hello';

    }

}
```

What I can't figure out is that both `Visitor.class.php` and `Settings.class.php` are setup the same way with the same constructor and yet one will work and the other won't.

So as you can see, I made a static string that everything throughout the app can add to, then later this string will be written to a file one time. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what's causing the problem, but you shouldn't be doing `$this::$logContent`: you're accessing a static variable from an instance. Use `self::$logContent` or `static::$logContent` instead. If that solves the problem, please let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thank you for pointing out that oversight. I just updated the code and unfortunately, it did not fix the issue.

Comment: And you use  `self::logContent` and `self::$logContent`! Only second one works.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. See this [3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/i3ubJ). Note: I fixed the typo @JustOnUnderMillions pointed out, and I stripped out the autoloader code and the `new Cache` for purposes of this demo.

Comment: After changing the `self::logContent` bug, it testet the script online with php5.5 and it works fine.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That was an error when I typed my post, not in the original code. *edited* Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: By the way, post the full error here, maybe you have set memory_limit way to low.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger, like xdebug? I strongly suspect there is some other code being invoked somewhere along the way. It's either that, or a much too low memory_limit, as @JustOnUnderMillions said.

Comment: There isn't enough info here to debug. You have a recursion somewhere that is eating up memory. Could be many things: broken autoloader, creating too many instances of App, could be your `Cache` class (which is missing from here)... Could be many things really.